# How to increase the performance of compare and Pick the objects using Two array-list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash, javascript-objects

Hi i am having two set of array objects, i need pick only the mrp is higher
in the updated list. i am able to get the Result using lodash map and Find functions. Its taking  more time for 10 to 15 k records. Is there anyway to increase the Performance. Here is My code.

```
var ExisitingData=[{"isActive" : true, 
    "barcode" : "8908001921015",     
    "mrp" : 2000, 
},
{"isActive" : true, 
    "barcode" : "8908001921015",     
    "mrp" : 1000, 
}
....15k]


var updatedData=[{"isActive" : true, 
    "barcode" : "8908001921015",     
    "mrp" : 4000, 
},
{"isActive" : true, 
    "barcode" : "8908001921015",     
    "mrp" : 1000, 
}
....15k]

var newData=[]
 _.map(result1, function (item) {
                var updateRecord = _.find(data3, {'barcode': item['barcode']});
                if (updateRecord) {
                    if (item['mrp'] > updateRecord['mrp']) {
                        newData.push(item);

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is `result1` and `data3`?

Comment: Your data has duplicate barcodes in both arrays? Or is your sample wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this efficiently with plain JavaScript, and it does not need much more code. I would suggest using an ES6 Map to key the *updatedData* by barcode, so you can do a fast lookup for each barcode you have in the *existingData*. Here I provide that Map as the `this` object to a `filter`:

```
let newData = existingData.filter(function (o) {
    return o.mrp > this.get(o.barcode);
}, new Map(updatedData.map( o => [o.barcode, o.mrp] )) );
```

```js
const existingData = [{
    "isActive" : true, 
    "barcode" : "8908001921015",     
    "mrp" : 2000, 
}, {
    "isActive" : true, 
    "barcode" : "2699001592228",
    "mrp" : 1000,
}];

const updatedData = [{
    "isActive" : true, 
    "barcode" : "2699001592228",     
    "mrp" : 4000, 
}, {
    "isActive" : true, 
    "barcode" : "8908001921015",     
    "mrp" : 1000, 
}];

let newData = existingData.filter(function (o) {
    return o.mrp > this.get(o.barcode);
}, new Map(updatedData.map( o => [o.barcode, o.mrp] )) );

console.log(newData);
```

So this iterates the second list once (in order to create the Map), and iterates the first list once (in order to filter it). The `Map#get` method runs in constant time, so this code runs in *O(n+m)* time, where *n* and *m* are the sizes of the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to run a lot faster (almost instantaneously for me with 15k items):

```
// group the two lists by barcode
const grouped = _.groupBy([...ExisitingData, ...updatedData], 'barcode');

// ignore any barcode that was added or removed
const pairs = _.filter(grouped, pair => pair.length === 2);

// filter by mrp change
const filteredPairs = _.filter(pairs, ([existingRecord, updatedRecord]) => updatedRecord.mrp > existingRecord.mrp);

// map to items
const newData = _.map(filteredPairs, ([existingRecord, updatedRecord]) => updatedRecord);
```

If you want to also include new items that were added (that is, when the barcode is present in the updatedData list but not in ExisitingData), you could include them like this:

```
const addedItems = _.differenceBy(updatedData, ExisitingData, 'barcode');
const newData2 = [...newData, ...addedItems];
```

---

non-ES6 version (been a while for me, hope I got this right):

```
// group the two lists by barcode
var grouped = _.groupBy(ExisitingData.concat(updatedData), 'barcode');

// ignore any barcode that was added or removed
var pairs = _.filter(grouped, function(pair) {
  return pair.length === 2;
});

// filter by mrp change
var filteredPairs = _.filter(pairs, function(pair) {
  return pair[1].mrp > pair[0].mrp;
});

// map result to item objects
var newData = _.map(filteredPairs, function(pair) {
  return pair[1];
});
```

Including new items:

```
var addedItems = _.differenceBy(updatedData, ExisitingData, 'barcode');
var newData2 = newData.concat(addedItems);
```